How to back select variations in Woocommerce
Our products have three variations, Color, Country and Size, in chronological order. Each country has their own Sizes, linked in the backend.
We have all colors available across all country sizes, but sizes are specific to Country. So there is a USKing& USQueen for US, and Europe King&Queen for Europe as well, with different prices.
Problem is, when the customer wants to change selection, they have to first, change the last selection, which makes other options available. I have attached pictures.
Ideally we need cross selection, like implemented at this product url

You can see how the user cannot select other country here, they have to clear selection from Bed Size to be able to edit it.
Any woocommerce settings that allows this? Is there any better implementation to this?
